# Yii count total members and show on landing page

Tags: yii

Hi I have an application that I would like to show total number of members on the landing page

I have tried adding

```
$connection = new \yii\db\Connection([

'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
]);
$connection->open();
$users = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user')->queryAll();
```

but the application just throws an error :

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Undefined variable: connection in index.php
```

do I need to create the connection first and then run the command?

Comment: You must have connection already. Try like this: `Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlQueryString)->quaeryAll();`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in the end

```
<?php $users = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user') ->queryScalar(); ?>
```

and then this to display the results

```
<? echo $users;?>
```